# Natural Boundary of Sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-b n^p}$

Tags: summation, analytic-continuation

Is it possible to prove for which $p$ does the sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-b n^p}$$

have a natural boundary on the imaginary b axis?

Comment: From the [Fabry gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry_gap_theorem), one has a natural boundary for $p>1$. (More precisely, the series in $z=e^{-b}$ has the unit circle as natural boundary. So the natural boundary in $b$ is $\text{Re }b=0$.)